# How to convert 8-digit number to date in r

Tags: r

Anyone please tell me How to convert from this format (4112013) to (04-11-2013) in R programming

Answer (score 4):

We can use `mdy` from `lubridate` in `R`

```
library(lubridate)
mdy(4112013)
#[1] "2013-04-11"
```

Answer (score 2):

If the date format you want is DMY (and if you want a `base` only solution):

```
thisDate <- "4112013"

thisDate <- if(nchar(thisDate) == 7){
  paste0("0",thisDate)
}

as.Date(thisDate, format = "%d%m%Y")
```

Comment: Why the downvote? We don't know what format the OP wants their dates in, so this merely provides a `base` alternative (which I've seen on SO `r` questions before) and a work around for bad values if this is the case.